# (JWT) RSA Encryption/decryption issue

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, jwt

I have a peculiar problem by following one of the tutorials on encrypting JWT.

Given the following code:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const passphrase = 'diogenes';

const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem'
  }
});

const sign = ({ messageId, tradeId, sessionToken }) => {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { messageId, tradeId, sessionToken },
    passphrase,
    { expiresIn: '10h' }
  );

  return token;
};

const verify = (jwtToken) => {
  const token = jwt.verify(jwtToken, passphrase);

  return token;
};

const signedToken = sign({ messageId: '1', tradeId: '2', sessionToken: '3' });

const encryptedToken = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(signedToken, 'base64'));

const decryptedToken = crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, encryptedToken);

console.log(decryptedToken.toString('base64'));
console.log(signedToken);
```

The values I am getting from decrypting are slightly different, not much, but enough to make token inverifiable.

For example:

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJtZXNzYWdlSWQiOiIxIiwidHJhZGVJZCI6IjIiLCJzZXNzaW9uVG9rZW4iOiIzIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczNTUxMDU4LCJleHAiOjE1NzM1ODcwNTh9zXIjsO8ExSOsmuGLzDh8JgclLjykiZjKBEiJ6mzLMAg=`

versus the original:

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXNzYWdlSWQiOiIxIiwidHJhZGVJZCI6IjIiLCJzZXNzaW9uVG9rZW4iOiIzIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczNTUxMDU4LCJleHAiOjE1NzM1ODcwNTh9.zXIjsO8ExSOsmuGLzDh8JgclLjykiZjKBEiJ6mzLMAg`

What is going on here?

Comment: *How* are they different, any examples?

Comment: I have updated for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON Web Token (JWT) consists of three parts separated by a dot (header, payload, signature), each of which is Base64Url-encoded, see [What is the JSON Web Token structure?](https://jwt.io/introduction/). Therefore, `signedToken` cannot be read into a buffer with the following statement:

```
Buffer.from(signedToken, 'base64')
```

which expects exactly one Base64 encoded string ([here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding)). The easiest way is to use the [binary](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)-encoding (which corresponds to the latin1- or ISO-8859-1-encoding) when reading into the buffer, since the individual parts are Base64-encoded and therefore compatible with this encoding:

```
const encryptedToken = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(signedToken, 'binary'));
```

and also for the output:

```
console.log(decryptedToken.toString('binary'));
```

Then both outputs are identical.